# Congruence Classes in the Guassian Integers?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gaussian-integers

For some non-zero Gaussian integer n, how can I find a finite upper bound for the number of congruence classes mod n?

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the norm! And notice that the Gausian norm is Euclidean!

Answer (score 5):

If $n = a + bi$, then there will be $a^2 + b^2$ distinct residue classes. Proving this in the $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ case may be done with the Euclidean algorithm (and some work.) However, it is a general fact of number fields that the number of distinct residue classes is given by a *norm* function.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the Euclidean Algorithm could be used for this? Thanks.